# 3 string pattern with Nested Loops

Tags: java, nested-loops

I am taking an introductory Java course and I have been stumped the last few days trying to get my pattern to come out correctly and was looking for some help as I have tried researching and rearranging the syntax of my code. Basically my code has to take 3 strings from the user, and a desired number of columns and rows from the user. The second string has to separate string 1 and string 2. And each rows should start off with either string 1 or string 2. For example if row 1 starts off with string 1 then row 2 should start off with string 2. And also no row should end with the separator string. Basically, I have been able to get the pattern to come out right but I cant figure out how to get the syntax to print out the correct number of rows and columns. An occurnece of string1 counts as a column, and an occurrence of string 2 counts as a column, however, the occurrence of the separator string does not count as a column. Basically I need to figure out how to get the correct number of rows and columns to out put by tomorrow night. Please help if you can. So far, my output comes out as each occurrence of string1+seperatorString+string2 being counted as a column. Here is my code so far:

```
package javaapplication37; 

import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication37 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;
        String word1 = "";
        String word2 = "";
        String sep = ""; 
        Scanner type = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your first set of characters");
        word1 = type.next();
        System.out.println("Enter your second set of characters");
        word2 = type.next();

        System.out.println("Enter a set of characters to seperate");
        sep = type.next();

        System.out.println("Enter number of rows");
        row = type.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter number of columns");
        column = type.nextInt();

        for (int moveRow = 1;moveRow <= row; ++moveRow){
            System.out.print(word1);
            for(int moveColumn = 0; moveColumn < 1; ++moveColumn){
                System.out.print(sep);
                for(int move1 = 0; moveColumn< 1 ; ++moveColumn){
                    System.out.print(word2);
                    if(moveRow != row){
                        System.out.print(sep);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int moveRow = 1;moveRow <= row; ++moveRow){
            System.out.print(word2);
            for(int moveColumn = 0; moveColumn < 1; ++moveColumn){
                System.out.print(sep);
                for(int move1 = 0; moveColumn< 1 ; ++moveColumn){
                    System.out.print(word1);
                    if(moveRow != row){
                        System.out.print(sep);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You question is unclear and doesn't make sense. Try explaining yourself again, but this time, with examples of possible inputs and outputs, and also with the purposes of the variables, word1, word2, sep, row and column.

Comment: Thanks for responding Jorge. I want to have 5 inputs from the user(three strings and an integer for row and an integer for column. The purpose of this is to generate a pattern that will out put the three strings where if string1 = aaa string2 = bbb string3 = 111 for 3 rows by 3 columns it will output :

Comment: Thanks for responding Jorge. I'm required to have five inputs from the user(three strings and an integer for row and an integer for column. The purpose of this is to generate a pattern that will output the three strings where if String1 = aaa String2 = bbb String3 = 111 for 3 rows by 3 columns it will output :    for line 1 (aaa111bbb111aaa) for line 2 (bbb111aaa111bbb)  for line 3 (aaa111bbb111aaa) Minus the parentheses. How should I go about setting up my for loops for the rows and columns to achieve this?